# How to format number separated with comma with positive sign (+) and dollar (sign)?

Tags: c#

I'm creating a helper to number format a number separated with a comma with a positive sign (+) and dollar ($). However, I already created that return a negative (-) sign. What I want to achieve a result is a positive (+) sign.

-$100 - I already have.

+$100 - This is the one I want to achieve.

Sample Code:

```
pricing.Price = 600;
RoomTypeDefaultPrice = 500;

var negative = string.Format(culture, "{0:C0}", pricing.Price - RoomTypeDefaultPrice);
```

Result: -$100

Answer (score 1):

You're close, you just need to use a [conditional format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--section-separator):

> The semicolon (;) is a conditional format specifier that applies different formatting to a number depending on whether its value is positive, negative, or zero. To produce this behavior, a custom format string can contain up to three sections separated by semicolons. These sections are described in the following table.

```
pricing.Price = 600;
RoomTypeDefaultPrice = 500;

var negative = string.Format(culture, "{0:+$#,##;-$#,##;$0}", pricing.Price - RoomTypeDefaultPrice);
```

It's essentially POSITIVE_FORMAT;NEGATIVE_FORMAT;ZERO_FORMAT

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/FCMSE83370)

Comment: @Michael Ah yes. Thanks! I hope there's a better solution to this than mine though :) I'm waiting to see what you come up with.

Comment: @MichaelRandall Yeah, I see it worked. But don't have a dollar sign. How to do that?

Comment: @John i think that's pretty much the most succinct solution, upvote